# Git: How can you manage multiple related projects in the same repo?

Tags: git

I’ve been developing a webapp that will now become a template for 3-4 different webapps. The core of each apps functionality will stay the same, about 70% of the code will be used by each app, the rest will differ in functionality, user roles, design, etc.

I would like to have the ability to update them separately of course. And also to have a simple method to fix bugs in the main template and implement features to all projects at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach is to always [clone](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) your template and then [add a new remote](https://docs.github.com/en/github/using-git/adding-a-remote), so and from this position, apply two strategies:

## Template changes

Template changes will only occur on the template project, never from its "clients". Its clients will only pull from the template.

## Client projects

Your client projects will pull from the template whenever a new version is ready and, besides that, will operate normally.

Naturally, you could do this using your favorite git-based application, like GitHub fork, for example.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I have tested this with some dummy repos and it should suit my needs perfectly. The only difficulty I see is managing various conflicts when Clients pull from the Template, but I've gotten familiar with PyCharms merge tool so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Just so I perfectly understand, with each Client I should set new remotes to their own repos, and keep a remote to the Template, right?

Comment: @hobuci you can do it without helpers as well. You can set up a remote, like ```git remote add template <url>``` and then ```git pull template master``` and ```git push template master``` according to your needs.

Comment: @hobuci all of them will have their default remote called origin. You can add a template remote for all of them and then you can pull/push from template by specifying it in the pull/push command as described in the previous command, while ```git pull``` and ```git push``` (without specifying the remote) will pull/push from/to your actual project repo.

Comment: Exactly what I have done, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @hobuci you are welcome. I'm glad this was sorted out.